# Is it possible to read a compressed file without extracting the file in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, zip, gzip

I'm building an app which requires reading a file inside a zipfile without extracting the file. Is there any library out there with this kind of function or can you give me some ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: If you could read a compressed file without uncompressing it, there wouldn't be no point in uncompressing at all, don't you think? Files would be permanently compressed.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez: It can be useful to extract a portion of compressed data into memory, an uncompressed stream that can be subsequently processed. For example, a SAX parser can be run on a compressed XML file, where portions of it are extracted, parsed, and either discarded or processed further.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez please ask first why im doing this before you comment. Thanks Alex Reynolds for clarifying it.

Comment: Are you speaking about a zip compressed file or about files in a zip archive?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez - It's not that impractical to have read-only files always compressed.  After all a Java JAR file is in fact just a zip file, and members are directly read from the file by the class loader without creating an intermediate .class file.  The problem is more with read-write files -- it's very inefficient to write to a zip file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unzip one buffer-ful of data at a time, and read through that, assuming that the file is text and is structured in a way that you can parse it incrementally (for example, XML data that is processed with a SAX parser).

Here is a routine I wrote that extracts data from a zip-stream and prints out a line at a time. You could modify it to print out or parse `N` characters, instead. Or you could add the lines to a line buffer, and process/parse a chunk of lines at once.

This uses [`zlib`](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html), and if this code is useful to you, feel free to use it:

```
#
# compile with -lz option in order to link in the zlib library
#

#include <zlib.h>

#define Z_CHUNK 2097152

int unzipFile(const char *fName) 
{
    z_stream zStream;
    char *zRemainderBuf = malloc(1);
    unsigned char zInBuf[Z_CHUNK];
    unsigned char zOutBuf[Z_CHUNK];
    char zLineBuf[Z_CHUNK];
    unsigned int zHave, zBufIdx, zBufOffset, zOutBufIdx;
    int zError;
    FILE *inFp = fopen(fName, "rbR");

    if (!inFp) { fprintf(stderr, "could not open file: %s\n", fName); return EXIT_FAILURE; }

    zStream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    zStream.zfree = Z_NULL;
    zStream.opaque = Z_NULL;
    zStream.avail_in = 0;
    zStream.next_in = Z_NULL;  

    zError = inflateInit2(&zStream, (15+32)); /* cf. http://www.zlib.net/manual.html */
    if (zError != Z_OK) { fprintf(stderr, "could not initialize z-stream\n"); return EXIT_FAILURE; }

    *zRemainderBuf = '\0';
    do {
        zStream.avail_in = fread(zInBuf, 1, Z_CHUNK, inFp);
        if (zStream.avail_in == 0)
            break;
        zStream.next_in = zInBuf;
        do {
            zStream.avail_out = Z_CHUNK;
            zStream.next_out = zOutBuf;
            zError = inflate(&zStream, Z_NO_FLUSH);
            switch (zError) {
                case Z_NEED_DICT:  { fprintf(stderr, "Z-stream needs dictionary!\n"); return EXIT_FAILURE; }
                case Z_DATA_ERROR: { fprintf(stderr, "Z-stream suffered data error!\n"); return EXIT_FAILURE; }
                case Z_MEM_ERROR:  { fprintf(stderr, "Z-stream suffered memory error!\n"); return EXIT_FAILURE; }
            }
            zHave = Z_CHUNK - zStream.avail_out;
            zOutBuf[zHave] = '\0';

            /* copy remainder buffer onto line buffer, if not NULL */
            if (zRemainderBuf) {
                strncpy(zLineBuf, zRemainderBuf, strlen(zRemainderBuf));
                zBufOffset = strlen(zRemainderBuf);
            }
            else
                zBufOffset = 0;

            /* read through zOutBuf for newlines */
            for (zBufIdx = zBufOffset, zOutBufIdx = 0; zOutBufIdx < zHave; zBufIdx++, zOutBufIdx++) {
                zLineBuf[zBufIdx] = zOutBuf[zOutBufIdx];
                if (zLineBuf[zBufIdx] == '\n') {
                    zLineBuf[zBufIdx] = '\0'; 
                    zBufIdx = -1;
                    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", zLineBuf);
                }
            }

            /* copy some of line buffer onto the remainder buffer, if there are remnants from the z-stream */
            if (strlen(zLineBuf) > 0) {
                if (strlen(zLineBuf) > strlen(zRemainderBuf)) {
                    /* to minimize the chance of doing another (expensive) malloc, we double the length of zRemainderBuf */
                    free(zRemainderBuf);
                    zRemainderBuf = malloc(strlen(zLineBuf) * 2);
                }
                strncpy(zRemainderBuf, zLineBuf, zBufIdx);
                zRemainderBuf[zBufIdx] = '\0';
            }
        } while (zStream.avail_out == 0);
    } while (zError != Z_STREAM_END);

    /* close gzip stream */
    zError = inflateEnd(&zStream);
    if (zError != Z_OK) { 
        fprintf(stderr, "could not close z-stream!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (zRemainderBuf)
        free(zRemainderBuf);

    fclose(inFp);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: thanks sir, i really appreciate your help. I will look at your code and study it.

Comment: I think he speaks about zip archives, so, even if your code would be helpful, the interesting part would be to find the beginning of the stream in the archive (and decompress it using the correct algorithm - store, inflate etc.)

Comment: It's unclear whether the OP means a "zip" file or simply a compressed file, but there are open source APIs available that can "crack" the zip file format, in addition to the zlib package which uncompresses the default compression of zip file members.